# Shorter way to say "split [user story] into tasks"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, single-word-requests

In [scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) (a project management methodology often used for software development), there are **user stories** (or *items*) which team members split into smaller **tasks** when they start working on them.

To describe that "splitting into tasks", in Finnish I'd simply say something like "Taskitetaan se." ("Let's split it into tasks." And yes, that's a horrible anglicism.)

What would be a shorter way to say that in English?

I'm tempted to just ["verb" the noun](http://www.thejakartaglobe.com/opinion/verbed-but-not-every-noun-would-like-to-stay-that-way/388240), and use something like "Let's task it". How acceptable or understandable would you find that?

Comment: Won't a simple "Let's split it" work? Or would that be ambiguous? (I.e., can items be split into anything other than tasks?)

Comment: @RegDwight: Good point! Usually that wouldn't be ambiguous (yeah, you can only split them into tasks). But having the work "task" somewhere in the phrase would be nice, if e.g. filling a short work hour report with something like "US-12: Planning; Splitting". Or hmm, maybe it's just a matter of getting used to. :)

Comment: The main problem I see with verbing *task* is that we already *have* such a verb, but with a different meaning ("to assign a task to", see e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/task), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/task#Verb)). So "Let's task it" would be understood as "Let's assign a task to it". Similarly, "Planning, Tasking" would not convey the meaning you have in mind. ("Let's taskenize it"? "Taskenizing"? That surely sounds horrible.)

Comment: Keep in mind that "task" is already a verb--(most commonly seen as a participle: someone is tasked to do something)--and so verbing the noun for another purpose is less than ideal. The other comments/answers have good suggestions for how to handle your situation.

Comment: @res, @RegDwight, what do you think about "Let's task it out", as suggested by [Ted Ballou](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/shorter-way-to-say-split-user-story-into-tasks/5306#5306)? (Is having "out" in the phrase sufficient to remove confusion with the other meaning of "task" as a verb?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work in a scrum environment. When we break down a user story we always say "Let's task it out"

Comment: Thanks, nice to know that also native speakers might use "task (out)" as a verb with this meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be better off talking about "breaking it down" rather than "splitting it." This carries a stronger sense of deconstructing the problem into its conceptual components. So:

> Let's break it down.

(Might sound bad in other contexts, but works fine here!)

Comment: I guess you're right, this is a more idiomatic way to say it (I've never been in a scrum team with native English speakers, so I don't know what they'd use.) As with RegDwight's comment, it might take me some time to get used to writing e.g. "US-12: Planning; Breaking it down". I'll try and see. :)

Comment: Looking back over your comments, maybe "task breakdown" would be less ambiguous. Good luck with the scrum - I hope the method works well for your team :)

Comment: @Rhodri: You're right - in context, it's clear to a native speaker what is meant.

Comment: (Forgot to add this earlier...) Thanks; I've actually applied scrum since 2005, and have generally been happy with it. (It ain't a silver bullet, and one should probably combine it with [XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_Programming) practices, but the key ideas of scrum and kanban do make sense, in my experience.)

Answer (score 0):

**"Let's divide it."**

This would imply that the user story is to be divided up into smaller tasks that should be be allocated to an individual. When a group divides the spoils everyone gets a share, when a group breaks something down it's just a pile of smaller bits without a sense of ownership.

Just my 2p.

Comment: Hmm, then again, in scrum, the team is collectively responsible for getting the whole user story done, whatever it takes (the team can basically self-organise in any way to that end). So there doesn't have to be *one* responsible person for each task. (Often there is, but "ownership" of individual tasks is not of central importance in any case.) But this gets quite off-topic here. :-)